# Record all users in a voice channel in discord.js v12

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to record a voice channel session with a bot.

The `VoiceReceiver` class has only one function `createStream()` and a debug event.

The `createStream()` function creates a new stream only for one user in a voice channel. But, I want to record every user in the voice chat at once, thus capturing the whole conversation that is going on.

I have thought of looping over all the users and creating a stream for each one but then I would have a lot of recordings. That is also assuming that all the streams would run in parallel.

Is there a way I can record every person's voice in the voice channel?

Answer (score 1):

From discordjs.guide:

> **What if I want to listen to multiple users?**
>
> You can create a stream for each user. However, you cannot make a single stream that will interpolate audio from multiple users in a channel–this is currently out of discord.js' scope.

So, you can only use your method.